# Loading JNI crashes with undefined symbols

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to link my native library to a java application but when I try to run it I get a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception complaining about missing symbols(`_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE`)

I compiled the shared library with g++ just like any other shared library.

This is my first try with JNI and I can't figure out how to get everything to link correctly.

Comment: Can you post the exact link line?  And can you verify that libstdc++ is being linked against?

Comment: of course: g++ ${CFLAGS} -shared -Wl,-soname,liblzw_compressor.so -o liblzw_compressor.so  compression_CompressedInputStream.o compression_CompressedOutputStream.o lzw.o

Comment: Just for the heck of it, can you try relinking without the `-Wl,-soname,liblzw_compressor.so` option?  Months and months ago I ran into something pretty similar and I think I was able to fix it by removing the `-Wl` option from my link line.  But I may be misremembering.

Comment: That actually seems to have fixed it for some reason, but now the JVM is crashing. Oh well, at least now I can debug the code! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try relinking without the `-Wl,-soname,liblzw_compressor.so` option.  If it works I can't tell you why, other than that months ago I had a very similar undefined symbol error (may have even been the same symbol) and ditching the `-Wl` option from my link line fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `c++filt` executable that comes with your toolchain to demangle the missing symbols. Then it's a matter of figuring out which part of your code isn't doing what it is supposed to do.

`nm` can be used to list the symbols defined in code. if you see that a symbol has a U on the same line it is undefined and can lead to this error. passing -E to gcc/g++ stops the compiler after the preprocessing step, which might also be useful.

The causes that I have had for this error in the past are essentially:

- not building something I thought I was building (it happens to the best of us)
- Calling convention mangling the symbol in an unexpected way